# iOS app pilling memory while segueing back and forth

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

In my iOS app when i seque from viewController A to B its using system memory which is ok.

But the problem is when i seque from viewController A to B and then back to A and again To B, this keeps pilling more and more memory.

Why its not releasing all the used memory when going back to view A.

I am using autorelease pool. and i am nilling the no longer required variables.

Note: i am using GCD in View B but i am also releasing the memory in GCD.

I dont know know why is this happening. Or is there a way to completely unload all the resources used by view B when i am in view A?

**UPDATE:**

I am not pusing back from B to A. i am just using the back button.

this is my segue from view A

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

@autoreleasepool {

PhotosCollectionViewController *photoCollection=[segue destinationViewController];
NSIndexPath *path=[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

// get the cell tag for the selected row
NSIndexPath *path1=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[path row] inSection:0];

UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path1];

[photoCollection setPassedID:[[elements objectAtIndex:path1.row] objectAtIndex:0]];
// set the title of the next view controller
[photoCollection setTitle:cell.textLabel.text];

photoCollection=nil;
path=nil;
path1=nil;

}

}
```

**EDIT**

the long running process that i am using in my view b in viewDidLoad

```
photoQueue=dispatch_queue_create("com.prepare.photos", nil);
dispatch_async(photoQueue, ^{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(goToBackground)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];


display_photos=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];




// iterate through photos array and create MWPhoto object out of it

// init ns cache
//myCache=[[NSCache alloc] init];

    int j=0;

    for(j=0;j<[photos count];j++){
        //NSLog(@"filename %@",[[photos objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0]);

        MWPhoto *mw=[MWPhoto photoWithFilePath:[self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[photos objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:0]]];

        [display_photos addObject:mw];
        mw=nil;


    }

    //dispatch_release(photoQueue);

});
```

Comment: I am using Instruments Activity monitor to monitor the memory usage.

Comment: why are you using an "`@autoreleasepool`" there?

Comment: to release the three references and free up the memory

Comment: i am executing a long process in view b through GCD. does it have anything to do with GCD because seguing to same view again and again would run the same task over and over?

Comment: I don't think you really understand what `@autoreleasepool` does. It doesn't really hurt, but this doesn't seem like a case where you'd typically use it (and it wouldn't make a functional difference if you'd leave it out). Setting the `photoCollection`, `path`, and `path1` references to `nil` is also pointless. Are you using ARC btw?

Comment: yes omz my app uses arc.

Comment: I guess you'll need to show some more code, e.g.that long-running process you mentioned. It doesn't look like the problem is in the snippet you've posted.

Comment: I dont think the problem is with long running process because i just disabled the long running process and it still causing the same problem

Comment: I posted the long running process in my question

Comment: Instruments shows that my app is leaking memory. Leaked Object # Address Size Responsible Library Responsible Frame
OS_dispatch_queue 1 0x1f5e1190 128 Bytes libdispatch.dylib _os_object_alloc

Comment: You've commented out the `dispatch_release`, why? This way, you're leaking the queue (it should come *after* the dispatched block though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question. The reason it was pilling up memory was that when ever i retrieved somedata from sqlite database, i closed the sqlite connection. So seguing to new view would reopen the database connection and that would cause excessive memory usage.

So the bottom line, dont close the sqlite database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Segues load new instances of view controller; therefore, using segue makes sense when you use it to navigate form view controller A to B.

```
A_1 -> B_1
```

However, if you are using segue to navigate from B to A, you are creating a new instance of view controller A instead of returning to your previous instance of view controller A.

> A_1 -> B_1 -> A_2

Segueing back and forth will result to this:

> A_1 -> B_1 -> A_2 -> B_2 -> A_3 ->  ...

Ideally, what you want is:

> A_1 -> B_1 -> A_1

(going back to A_1 from B_1)

To achieve this, you might want to use this method for the button that navigates from view controller B to A.

```
- (IBAction)backButton:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){
            NSLog(@"View controller dismissed");
            // things to do after dismissing
        }];
}
```